# WCF does not support optional parameter

Tags: wcf, optional-parameters

I make my windows communication service parameter optional (in Operation Contract), but on the client when I dont want to pass optional parameter, error happens and requires this parameter. How can I fix it?

Comment: Show us your code pls

Comment: WCF does not support overloading and optional parameters. If you do not pass this parameter, the default value of the type will be used (int type is 0, string is null), you can consider using the `Isrequired` attribute of the data contract to reconstruct the method.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/data-member-default-values